# How to delete a Spring Cloud Data Flow application properties?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

A stream is created, eg. `http | log` then the stream is deployed by using a properties file, eg.:

```
app.http.foo.bar=value
```

I'm trying now to delete the property `app.http.foo.bar`.

I have tried to:

- Remove it from the properties file: KO, scdf stores and merges the properties
- Set an empty value `app.http.foo.bar=`: KO, scdf server throws an exception that null is not supported

Any hint? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using out of the box apps for `http` and `log` ?

Once registered with the SCDF system, the property can not be removed and the only way you can remove is at the application compile time (by removing the property from the properties file before building).

Comment: It is not about removing the property, I mean physically, but removing the value configured for that app